# Phonegap's em unit not working correctly

Tags: android, css, cordova

I am developing a mobile app with phonegap. I'm running into some issues with the viewport I think;

I've tested the web app in Google Chrome with the mobile emulator and everything is scaled fine.
The same as in my mobile chrome browser on my HTC One M8 (Android 4.4.4) as you can see on this screenshot.

[image: Correct font sizes]

My viewport meta tag is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1" />
```

But if I run the app with phonegap (`phonegap serve`) and it's Debug app from the play store, the font-sizes are scaled incorrectly, as you can see here:

[image: Incorrect font sizes]

Answer (score 0):

AppGyver's [Steroids tooling](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids) comes with Crosswalk for Android. Crosswalk lets you use an up-to-date fork of Chromium instead of the platform WebView – this fixes many rendering issues. The tooling also provides you with enhanced access to the Chrome Inspector for debugging what happens in the Webview.

You can [use Steroids in your Cordova project](http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/cli/usage-with-cordova/) directly without modifying any files, so check it out.

(Disclaimer: I'm a programmer for AppGyver.)